# Cannot see address on geth instance console in the dev network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask, rpc

I am trying to develop a ethereum private network & i am using a single dev node.

I startup my local dev instance of geth using this command below.

```
geth --mine --dev --rpc --rpccorsdomain="chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn"
```

Now the RPC is exposed this is the only instance. I have installed metamask in my browser & then i connected to the private network at the default port which is `localhost:8545`, i pressed create account.. & as expected it created an account with a new address.

When i go to my geth console, i tried to list my all the accounts in the running private network & expected the newly created account address in metamask to appear.. but nope.

When i do a `eth.accounts` or `personal.listAccounts` i don't see the account i created in metamask, what am i missing here ?

Please keep in mind that i have only run on geth instance. What is more weird is that when i do an `eth.sendTrasanction` to the newly created address in metamask, metamask shows me the correct amount i transferred.

Also i cannot send transaction from metamask address to an address in my geth instance, i get an failed transaction with an error message saying invalid recipient.

Comment: `geth` stores the accounts in $HOME/.ethereum/keystore directory, you have to create it with `geth account new` . There can't be "invalid recipient" error because the account does not need to be created before funds send to it. You can send some money to a nonexistent account like 0x8888888888888888888888888888888888888888 and it will be created during transfer.

Comment: So what exactly happens when I create an account in metamask?

Comment: I don't know, probably metamask just generates private/public keys wihtout even connecting to your node.